# npm error for more than 150 packages for react application

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

Issue:
When running the command npm install --legacy-peer-deps for the provided package.json, the following error is encountered:

```
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\SPORTSUI\SPORTS-ui-repository\node_modules\gifsicle
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node lib/install.js
npm ERR! (node:15832) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR!   ‼ read ECONNRESET
npm ERR!   ‼ gifsicle pre-build test failed
npm ERR!   i compiling from source
npm ERR!   × Error: Command failed: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "autoreconf -ivf"
npm ERR! 'autoreconf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at C:\SPORTSUI\SPORTS-ui-repository\node_modules\execa\index.js:231:11
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)        
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\kite\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-14T04_59_42_022Z-debug-0.log
```

Details:

Package.json: Provided package.json configuration.
Error: Error encountered during npm install.
Attempts: Googled for solutions but no success.
Request:
Seeking assistance to resolve the error encountered during the npm install process. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

```json
{
  "name": "animal-react-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": " gg",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=5",
    "node": ">=8.15.1"
  },
  "author": "kh",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "build:dev": "webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout",
    "build:ple": "webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.ple.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config internals/webpack/webpack.local.babel.js --disable-host-check",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js --disable-host-check",
    "ple": "webpack-dev-server --config internals/webpack/webpack.ple.babel.js --disable-host-check",
    "prod": "webpack-dev-server --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --disable-host-check",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:css",
    "lint:css": "stylelint app/**/*.js",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint:eslint:fix": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --fix",
    "lint:js": "npm run lint:eslint -- . ",
    "lint:staged": "lint-staged",
    "prettify": "prettier --write"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "> 1%",
    "IE 10"
  ],
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "npm run lint:eslint:fix",
      "git add --force"
    ],
    "*.json": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add --force"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adobe/cq-react-editable-components": "~1.0.3",
    "@adobe/cq-spa-component-mapping": "~1.0.3",
    "@adobe/cq-spa-page-model-manager": "~1.0.4",
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^1.0.8",
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.3.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.4.3",
    "@gh/accordions": "^1.2.1",
    "@gh/buttons": "^1.5.0",
    "@gh/inputs": "^1.7.1",
    "@gh/lines": "^1.0.2",
    "@gh/loaders": "^1.0.5",
    "@gh/modals": "^1.3.0",
    "@gh/notifications": "^1.3.0",
    "@gh/pagination": "^1.2.1",
    "@gh/selects": "^1.4.1",
    "@gh/tables": "^1.0.3",
    "@gh/tabs": "^1.0.5",
    "@gh/theme": "^1.0.2",
    "@animalrf/react-button": "^1.4.8",
    "@animalrf/react-forms": "^1.3.12",
    "@animalrf/react-grid": "^1.3.10",
    "@animalrf/react-header-block": "^1.0.3",
    "@animalrf/react-icon": "^1.0.3",
    "@animalrf/react-table": "^1.4.7",
    "@animalrf/react-theme": "^1.3.9",
    "antd": "3.26.20",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-switch-button-react": "^1.2.0",
    "chalk": "^2.4.2",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.0",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "connected-react-router": "6.4.0",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.22.1",
    "export-from-json": "^1.3.4",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "focus-trap-react": "^8.3.2",
    "fontfaceobserver": "2.1.0",
    "highcharts": "^9.2.2",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.1.0",
    "history": "4.9.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "3.3.0",
    "immer": "3.0.0",
    "invariant": "2.2.4",
    "ip": "1.1.5",
    "is-core-module": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^1.6.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "prop-types": "15.8.1",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-contenteditable": ">=3.2.0",
    "react-cron-generator": "^1.2.12",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-datepicker": "2.0.0",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom-factories": "^1.0.2",
    "react-json-to-csv": "^1.0.4",
    "react-querybuilder": "^3.12.1",
    "react-redux": "6.0.0",
    "react-responsive": "^8.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "1.0.2",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "sanitize.css": "8.0.0",
    "styled-components": "5.0.0",
    "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.24",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "url-regex": "^5.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.16.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/core": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.12.17",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "7.4.0",
    "@animalrf/react-accordion": "^1.8.0",
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^1.1.0",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "3.1.3",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.5",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "3.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.24",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "5.0.2",
    "compare-versions": "3.4.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "coveralls": "3.0.3",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "4.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.17.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "1.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.6.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.8.0",
    "jest-cli": "24.7.1",
    "jest-dom": "3.1.3",
    "jest-styled-components": "7.0.3",
    "lint-staged": "8.1.5",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "offline-plugin": "5.0.6",
    "pre-commit": "1.2.2",
    "prettier": "1.17.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "0.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6",
    "react-testing-library": "6.1.2",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.3",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "10.0.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "2.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "1.6.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "2.3.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.2.3",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "4.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.6.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.24.3",
    "webpack-pwa-manifest": "4.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `nom`? or did you attempt to tag `npm`?

Comment: @vallentin thanks for your response... it should be npm...can you let me know how to fix it

Comment: I saw the question through the `nom` tag, so I am of limited use. What I can infer from the error, is that you're using Windows, while `autoreconf` is a GNU tool. I checked the the gifsicle NPM module issue tracker, and there is an [issue of your error](https://github.com/imagemin/gifsicle-bin/issues/79). Also [gifsicle-bin](https://github.com/imagemin/gifsicle-bin) refers to using [imagemin-gifsicle](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-gifsicle) instead