# Error when running npm install npm-check - gifsicle pre-build test failed

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, gifsicle

I'm new to using npm, and I encountered an issue when trying to run the command npm install npm-check. Despite searching online, I haven't been able to find a solution. Below, I've provided my package.json and package-lock.json files for reference. Could someone please assist me in resolving this error?

```
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\SPORTSUI\SPORTS-ui-repository\node_modules\gifsicle
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node lib/install.js
npm ERR! (node:5224) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
npm ERR!   ‼ read ECONNRESET
npm ERR!   ‼ gifsicle pre-build test failed
npm ERR!   i compiling from source
npm ERR!   × Error: Command failed: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "autoreconf -ivf"
npm ERR! 'autoreconf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at C:\SPORTSUI\SPORTS-ui-repository\node_modules\execa\index.js:231:11
npm ERR!     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\kite\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-03-19T02_58_02_687Z-debug-0.log

package-lock.json

{
  "name": "lap-react-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "lap-react-boilerplate",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "@adobe/aem-react-editable-components": "^2.1.1",
        "@adobe/aem-spa-component-mapping": "^1.1.1",
        "@adobe/aem-spa-page-model-manager": "^1.5.0",
        "@ant-design/compatible": "^5.1.2",
        "@ant-design/icons": "^5.3.0",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.1.0",
        "@sports/accordions": "^4.0.1",
        "@sports/buttons": "4.0.1",
        "@sports/icons": "4.0.1",
        "@sports/inputs": "^4.0.1",
        "@sports/lines": "^4.0.0",
        "@sports/loaders": "^4.0.0",
        "@sports/modals": "^4.0.1",
        "@sports/notifications": "^4.0.1",
        "@sports/pagination": "^4.0.1",
        "@sports/radio-buttons": "^4.0.1",
        "@sports/selects": "^4.0.1",
        "@sports/tables": "^4.0.0",
        "@sports/tabs": "^4.0.1",
        "@sports/theme": "^1.1.4",
        "antd": "^5.14.0",
        "axios": "^1.6.7",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
        "bootstrap-switch-button-react": "^1.2.0",
        "chalk": "^5.3.0",
        "chokidar": "^3.6.0",
        "compression": "^1.7.4",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "date-fns": "^3.3.1",
        "export-from-json": "^1.7.4",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "focus-trap-react": "^10.2.3",
        "fontfaceobserver": "^2.3.0",
        "highcharts": "^11.3.0",
        "highcharts-react-official": "^3.2.1",
        "history": "^5.3.0",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2",
        "immer": "^10.0.3",
        "invariant": "^2.2.4",
        "ip": "^2.0.0",
        "is-core-module": "^2.13.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "minimist": "^1.2.8",
        "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^2.0.25",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.0",
        "react-contenteditable": "^3.3.7",
        "react-cron-generator": "^2.0.11",
        "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
        "react-datepicker": "^6.1.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom-factories": "^1.0.2",
        "react-json-to-csv": "^1.2.0",
        "react-querybuilder": "^6.5.5",
        "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
        "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.22.0",
        "react-select": "^5.8.0",
        "redux": "^5.0.1",
        "redux-saga": "^1.3.0",
        "redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
        "reselect": "^5.1.0",
        "sanitize.css": "^13.0.0",
        "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
        "ua-parser-js": "^1.0.37",
        "url-regex": "^5.0.0",
        "xlsx": "^0.19.3"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.23.9",
        "@babel/core": "^7.23.9",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
        "@babel/register": "^7.23.7",
        "@lcdp/offline-plugin": "^5.1.1",
        "@webpack-cli/serve": "^2.0.5",
        "babel-core": "^4.7.16",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
        "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.3",
        "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
        "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^8.2.25",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
        "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
        "compare-versions": "^6.1.0",
        "compression-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
        "coveralls": "^3.1.1",
        "css-loader": "^6.10.0",
        "eslint": "^8.56.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.8",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "^1.3.2",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "html-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
        "i": "^0.3.7",
        "image-webpack-loader": "^4.2.0",
        "imports-loader": "^5.0.0",
        "jest-cli": "^29.7.0",
        "jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
        "jest-styled-components": "^7.2.0",
        "lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
        "npm": "^10.4.0",
        "null-loader": "^4.0.1",
        "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
        "prettier": "^3.2.5",
        "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
        "react-testing-library": "^8.0.1",
        "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
        "shelljs": "^0.8.5",
        "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
        "stylelint": "^16.2.1",
        "stylelint-config-recommended": "^14.0.0",
        "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
        "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.0.0",
        "svg-url-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.10",
        "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.90.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
        "webpack-dev-middleware": "^7.0.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
        "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.26.1",
        "webpack-pwa-manifest": "^4.0.0",
        "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.20"
      }
    },


    "node_modules/punycode": {
      "version": "2.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://oneartifactoryprod.sports.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/punycode/-/punycode-2.3.1.tgz",
      "dev": true,
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=6"
      }
    },

    "node_modules/gifsicle": {
      "version": "4.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://oneartifactoryprod.sports.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/gifsicle/-/gifsicle-4.0.1.tgz",
      "dev": true,
      "hasInstallScript": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "bin-build": "^3.0.0",
        "bin-wrapper": "^4.0.0",
        "execa": "^1.0.0",
        "logalot": "^2.0.0"
      },
      "bin": {
        "gifsicle": "cli.js"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=6"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/cross-spawn": {
      "version": "6.0.5",
      "resolved": "https://oneartifactoryprod.sports.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/cross-spawn/-/cross-spawn-6.0.5.tgz",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "nice-try": "^1.0.4",
        "path-key": "^2.0.1",
        "semver": "^5.5.0",
        "shebang-command": "^1.2.0",
        "which": "^1.2.9"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=4.8"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/execa": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "resolved": "https://oneartifactoryprod.sports.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/execa/-/execa-1.0.0.tgz",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "cross-spawn": "^6.0.0",
        "get-stream": "^4.0.0",
        "is-stream": "^1.1.0",
        "npm-run-path": "^2.0.0",
        "p-finally": "^1.0.0",
        "signal-exit": "^3.0.0",
        "strip-eof": "^1.0.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=6"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/get-stream": {
      "version": "4.1.0",
      "resolved": "https://oneartifactoryprod.sports.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/get-stream/-/get-stream-4.1.0.tgz",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "pump": "^3.0.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=6"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/path-key": {
      "version": "2.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://oneartifactoryprod.sports.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/path-key/-/path-key-2.0.1.tgz",
      "dev": true,
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=4"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/semver": {
      "version": "5.7.2",
      "resolved": "https://oneartifactoryprod.sports.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/semver/-/semver-5.7.2.tgz",
      "dev": true,
      "bin": {
        "semver": "bin/semver"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/shebang-command": {
      "version": "1.2.0",
      "resolved": "https://oneartifactoryprod.sports.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/shebang-command/-/shebang-command-1.2.0.tgz",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "shebang-regex": "^1.0.0"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=0.10.0"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/gifsicle/node_modules/which": {
      "version": "1.3.1",
      "resolved": "https://oneartifactoryprod.sports.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm-virtual/which/-/which-1.3.1.tgz",
      "dev": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "isexe": "^2.0.0"
      },
      "bin": {
        "which": "bin/which"
      }
    },
   




  }
}

package.json
{
  "name": "lap-react-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A ",
  "author": "Team",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "build:dev": "webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout",
    "build:ple": "webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.ple.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout",
    "start": "webpack serve --mode development",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --config internals/webpack/webpack.dev.babel.js  --disable-host-check",
    "ple": "webpack-dev-server --config internals/webpack/webpack.ple.babel.js  --disable-host-check",
    "prod": "webpack-dev-server --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js  --disable-host-check",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:css",
    "lint:css": "stylelint app/**/*.js",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint:eslint:fix": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --fix",
    "lint:js": "npm run lint:eslint -- . ",
    "lint:staged": "lint-staged",
    "prettify": "prettier --write"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 2 versions",
    "> 1%",
    "IE 10"
  ],
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "npm run lint:eslint:fix",
      "git add --force"
    ],
    "*.json": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add --force"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "babel-core": "6.26.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adobe/aem-react-editable-components": "^2.1.1",
    "@adobe/aem-spa-component-mapping": "^1.1.1",
    "@adobe/aem-spa-page-model-manager": "^1.5.0",
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^5.1.2",
    "@ant-design/icons": "^5.3.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.1.0",
    "@sports/accordions": "^4.0.1",
    "@sports/buttons": "4.0.1",
    "@sports/icons": "4.0.1",
    "@sports/inputs": "^4.0.1",
    "@sports/lines": "^4.0.0",
    "@sports/loaders": "^4.0.0",
    "@sports/modals": "^4.0.1",
    "@sports/notifications": "^4.0.1",
    "@sports/pagination": "^4.0.1",
    "@sports/radio-buttons": "^4.0.1",
    "@sports/selects": "^4.0.1",
    "@sports/tables": "^4.0.0",
    "@sports/tabs": "^4.0.1",
    "@sports/theme": "^1.1.4",
    "antd": "^5.14.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.7",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "bootstrap-switch-button-react": "^1.2.0",
    "chalk": "^5.3.0",
    "chokidar": "^3.6.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cronstrue": "^2.48.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "date-fns": "^3.3.1",
    "export-from-json": "^1.7.4",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "focus-trap-react": "^10.2.3",
    "fontfaceobserver": "^2.3.0",
    "highcharts": "^11.3.0",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.2.1",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.2",
    "immer": "^10.0.3",
    "invariant": "^2.2.4",
    "ip": "^2.0.0",
    "is-core-module": "^2.13.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "minimist": "^1.2.8",
    "multiselect-react-dropdown": "^2.0.25",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.10.0",
    "react-contenteditable": "^3.3.7",
    "react-cron-generator": "^2.0.11",
    "react-csv": "^2.2.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom-factories": "^1.0.2",
    "react-json-to-csv": "^1.2.0",
    "react-querybuilder": "^6.5.5",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.0",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "redux": "^5.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^3.1.0",
    "reselect": "^5.1.0",
    "sanitize.css": "^13.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.8",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2",
    "ua-parser-js": "^1.0.37",
    "url-regex": "^5.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.19.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.23.7",
    "@lcdp/offline-plugin": "^5.1.1",
    "@webpack-cli/serve": "^2.0.5",
    "babel-core": "^4.7.16",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.3",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^8.2.25",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "^5.2.2",
    "compare-versions": "^6.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "coveralls": "^3.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.8",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "^1.3.2",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.6.0",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "imports-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "jest-cli": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "jest-styled-components": "^7.2.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
    "npm": "^10.4.0",
    "null-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^3.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^18.2.0",
    "react-testing-library": "^8.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.5",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.4",
    "stylelint": "^16.2.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "^14.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "^0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "^1.0.0",
    "svg-url-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.10",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.90.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^7.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.26.1",
    "webpack-pwa-manifest": "^4.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.20"
  }
}
```

Comment: check this out
https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-gifsicle/issues/33

Comment: You were shown where to find existing _gifsicle_ issues in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78169879/283366). Why aren't you looking there before asking here?

Comment: In fact, this is an exact duplicate of your last question [npm error for more than 150 packages for react application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78169879/npm-error-for-more-than-150-packages-for-react-application)